# Oxidation number of oxygen atoms in oxygen difluoride

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, oxidation-state

My textbook says:

> Oxygen is assigned an oxidation number of $+1$ in oxygen difluoride. The number assigned to each Oxygen atom will depend upon the bonding state of oxygen but this number would now be a positive figure only.

Can there be multiple bonding states for oxygen in oxygen difluoride?

What can be the oxidation state of each oxygen atom in oxygen difluoride?

Answer (score 7):

[Oxygen difluoride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen_difluoride) $\ce{OF2}$ has a single oxygen atom. You must mean [dioxygen difluoride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dioxygen_difluoride) $\ce{O2F2}$.

The rules are the same as for hydrogen peroxide.

Both oxygen atoms in $\ce{O2F2}$  are equivalent, so their oxidation number is +1.